Databricks 15.4 LTS throws error connecting to Azure Key Vault
I have a scala application running on Java 17 on Databricks 15.4 (ARM cluster) When executing the below code
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.models.KeyVaultSecret
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder

val cred = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build()

val keyVaultClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
    .vaultUrl("https://my-key-vault-name.vault.azure.net/")
    .credential(cred)
    .buildClient()

val result = keyVaultClient.getSecret("secret-name")
println(result.getValue())

it throws the following error. If I use an AMD cluster instead of ARM cluster it works without issues.
UncheckedIOException: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException
Caused by: StacklessClosedChannelException: 
    at com.azure.core.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClient.sendSync(NettyAsyncHttpClient.java:201)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineNextSyncPolicy.processSync(HttpPipelineNextSyncPolicy.java:51)
    at com.azure.core.http.policy.HttpLoggingPolicy.processSync(HttpLoggingPolicy.java:175)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineNextSyncPolicy.processSync(HttpPipelineNextSyncPolicy.java:53)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.policy.InstrumentationPolicy.processSync(InstrumentationPolicy.java:101)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineNextSyncPolicy.processSync(HttpPipelineNextSyncPolicy.java:53)
    at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.implementation.KeyVaultCredentialPolicy.processSync(KeyVaultCredentialPolicy.java:386)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineNextSyncPolicy.processSync(HttpPipelineNextSyncPolicy.java:53)
    at com.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy.attemptSync(RetryPolicy.java:217)
    at com.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy.attemptSync(RetryPolicy.java:233)
    at com.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy.attemptSync(RetryPolicy.java:233)
    at com.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy.attemptSync(RetryPolicy.java:233)
    at com.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy.processSync(RetryPolicy.java:161)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineNextSyncPolicy.processSync(HttpPipelineNextSyncPolicy.java:53)
    at com.azure.core.http.policy.AddHeadersPolicy.processSync(AddHeadersPolicy.java:66)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineNextSyncPolicy.processSync(HttpPipelineNextSyncPolicy.java:53)
    at com.azure.core.http.policy.HttpPipelineSyncPolicy.processSync(HttpPipelineSyncPolicy.java:51)
    at com.azure.core.http.policy.UserAgentPolicy.processSync(UserAgentPolicy.java:174)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipelineNextSyncPolicy.processSync(HttpPipelineNextSyncPolicy.java:53)
    at com.azure.core.http.HttpPipeline.sendSync(HttpPipeline.java:138)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.SyncRestProxy.send(SyncRestProxy.java:62)

I ensured

I have permissions to access the azure resource. In fact it works on a Databricks 13.x cluster on Spark 3.4.2 and Java 8.
The necessary jar's are installed and the types are resolved without issues.
There is no restrictions on the subnet / net that disallows physical access to the resource.

Any pointers to look for ?
Update :
The code would need the maven package azure-identity to be installed in the cluster libraries.
Update 2 :
After following the suggestion from @dileepRaj below included the azure-natty package, get the following error. The full project is here. https://github.com/soundarmoorthy/azure-keyvault-sample/tree/main
24/12/17 18:33:57 ERROR Uncaught throwable from user code: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.azure.core.util.TracingOptions com.azure.core.util.ClientOptions.getTracingOptions()'
    at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder.buildInnerClient(SecretClientBuilder.java:238)
    at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder.buildClient(SecretClientBuilder.java:158)
    at org.soundar.App$.main(App.scala:17)
    at $line7b06f0760e9f40c48a6b927d9a2a817327.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4069058988444872:2)
    at $line7b06f0760e9f40c48a6b927d9a2a817327.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4069058988444872:45)
    at $line7b06f0760e9f40c48a6b927d9a2a817327.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4069058988444872:47)
    at $line7b06f0760e9f40c48a6b927d9a2a817327.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4069058988444872:49)
    at $line7b06f0760e9f40c48a6b927d9a2a817327.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-4069058988444872:51)
    at $line7b06f0760e9f40c48a6b927d9a2a817327.$read$$iw.<init>(command-4069058988444872:53)
    at $line7b06f0760e9f40c48a6b927d9a2a817327.$read.<init>(command-4069058988444872:55)
    at $line7b06f0760e9f40c48a6b927d9a2a817327.$read$.<init>(command-4069058988444872:59)
    at $line7b06f0760e9f40c48a6b927d9a2a817327.$read$.<clinit>(command-4069058988444872)
    at $line7b06f0760e9f40c48a6b927d9a2a817327.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at $line7b06f0760e9f40c48a6b927d9a2a817327.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at $line7b06f0760e9f40c48a6b927d9a2a817327.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:747)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1020)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:36)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:116)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:567)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:594)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:564)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:201)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$3(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:268)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.threadSafeTrapExit(DriverLocal.scala:1624)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:1582)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:1506)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.executeCommand$1(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:268)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$2(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:238)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at scala.Console$.withErr(Console.scala:196)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$1(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:235)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at scala.Console$.withOut(Console.scala:167)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$33(DriverLocal.scala:1146)
    at com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:45)
    at com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.runWith(UCSHandle.scala:104)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$28(DriverLocal.scala:1137)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:426)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:216)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:424)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:418)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:99)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:472)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:455)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:99)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$1(DriverLocal.scala:1073)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$.$anonfun$maybeSynchronizeExecution$4(DriverLocal.scala:1534)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:750)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2(DriverWrapper.scala:786)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:778)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$3(DriverWrapper.scala:818)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.executeThunkAndCaptureResultTags$1(UsageLogging.scala:669)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperationWithResultTags$4(UsageLogging.scala:687)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:426)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:216)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:424)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:418)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.withAttributionContext(DriverWrapper.scala:72)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:472)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:455)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.withAttributionTags(DriverWrapper.scala:72)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags(UsageLogging.scala:664)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperationWithResultTags$(UsageLogging.scala:582)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.recordOperationWithResultTags(DriverWrapper.scala:72)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:818)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommandAndGetError(DriverWrapper.scala:685)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:730)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$runInnerLoop$1(DriverWrapper.scala:560)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:426)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:216)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:424)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:418)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.withAttributionContext(DriverWrapper.scala:72)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:560)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:482)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:290)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)


Can you try increasing the driver memory and retry again?

which version of io.netty are you loading in your cluster?

@eshirvana I don't directly use netty. but the azure-identity package v1.11.1 seems to use netty 4.1.96.Final

@DileepRajNarayanThumula No impact after changing driver memory.

After analysing the logs bit closer I do see the following in driver logs.
ChannelInitializer: Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0xd951e2f0]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.<init>(io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpDecoderConfig, boolean, boolean)'
24/12/10 18:10:53 ERROR RetryPolicy: {"az.sdk.message":"Retry attempts have been exhausted.","exception":"io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException","tryCount":3}

When I tried your approach I have received an ERROR
command-417994642726454:3: error: object azure is not a member of package com import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient

As you mentioned you are using the ARM cluster.
I found this on the web you can use netty for authentication & sdk  include it in the pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-core-http-netty</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.4</version>
</dependency>

I have tried the below aproach using pyspark.
Below is my Azure databricks cluster configuration:


Next I have tried the below code:
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
client_id = "<YOUR CLINET ID>"
client_secret = "<YOUR CLIENT SECRET>"
tenant_id = "<YOUR TENAT ID>"
vault_url = "https://dileeprajnarayan-kv.vault.azure.net/"
secret_name = "new1"
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url, credential)
secret = secret_client.get_secret(secret_name)
print(f"Secret value for the secret '{secret_name}' is: {secret.value}")


In the above code I am Authenticating using ClientSecretCredential & Creating a SecretClient
Next Retrieving the secret

Let me try out the solution

Hi, https://github.com/soundarmoorthy/azure-keyvault-sample/tree/main. Updated the question with the new error. After adding reference to azure-core-http-netty found other incompatible API calls. I probably think it has to do with conflicts between spark netty dependencies and azure netty expectations.
I cannot use client_id, client_secret.

I think the issue seems to be the version of azure-identity and azure-security-keyvault-secrets. I was using a newer version whereas the older version of the jar worked. Use azure sdk bom v1.2.19 instead of v1.2.29.
This is how to setup the bom file. Notice that fro all azure sdk client libraries we don't mention versions individually.
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.19</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

In this case if we use azure-sdk bom version 1.2.29 or 1.2.30 it failed with the exception. It succeeds if the version is 1.2.19, with java 17, arm cluster, Databricks cluster 15.4 LTS.
